# Jumbotron issue with different screen ratios

Tags: css, sass, bootstrap-4

I came upon a problem while designing a jumbotron for a website.
It's outside the container. Created a background for it, set background-size to cover, worked great.

When I opened the front page on a wider screen, the jumbotron became larger and there were gaps since the background image was too wide.

I then tried background-size: 100% 100%, thinking the image would stretch. No changes. Thought I perhaps had a margin/padding issue. No changes again.

Is this a problem with the image or the jumbotron? I'm not sure how to solve this. No matter what image I pick, it behaves very differently on different devices.

Comment: Maybe show some code so we can all stare at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Behaving differently on different devices is not a bug, it's a feature. Having said that, try this...

```
background-image: url(INSERT_URL_HERE);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
background-position: center;
background-attachment: fixed;
```

Comment: I tried this, it now stretches to the top, left and right side but about an inch from the bottom of the jumbotron is blank. I tried inspecting the element in my browser and everything else seems fine. Tried putting !important next to all of this and nothing different happened.

Comment: Please give us the HTML code that pertains to your jumbotron and surrounding elements so we can help you efficiently without guessing.

Comment: None of it helped for the image I wanted to use. Changing it a bit in inkscape and exporting it again combined with what you provided me with helped.
I really don't know what caused this. They're nearly identical.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the image to stretch to fit the full element (even if it means losing proportion), you need to set `background-attachment` to fixed and the `background-size` to 100%. Like:

```
 .jumbotron {
     background-image: url(image.url);
     background-size: 100% 100%;
     background-attachment: fixed;
  }
```

Working example:

https://jsfiddle.net/4w9u7m1a/2/

Comment: Didn't work, it now behaves as if I've set the background image to a container even though the jumbotron itself is outside of it. It's pretty confusing. Tried inspecting it in my browser and there aren't any issues with the html. I really have no idea what to do.

Comment: Definitely provide the html for the jumbotron. It doesn't make sense (to me) what you mean by "it is outside of it".